# Java - True/False per Enum value

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to figure out what is the best solution for my problem.

I have an object where the status may be one of three possibilities but it can change during run time. I have three status flags that the object can be.

I have no experience with `ENUM` and trying to figure out if this is the best way.

I want to be able to set a specific flag to `true` or `false` and then be able to set another one.  I need to be able to get the status of each flag as well for when I iterate through a list of these objects within a array list.

```
class Patient 
{


//REST OF the object

public enum Status 
{
     INPATIENT(false),
     OUTPATIENT(false),
     EMERGENCY(false);


      private final boolean isStatus;

      Status(boolean isStatus) 
      {
        this.isStatus = isStatus;
      }

      public boolean isStatus()
      {
        return this.isStatus;
      }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm confused. Can a patient have more than one status at the same time?

Comment: What you've written would be more appropriate if you wanted to encode other information with each enum value (e.g. you wanted each enum value to have an `isUrgent()` method, which was true for EMERGENCY and false for the other two).  But that boolean is set for (all instances of) each enum value, no matter how many enums currently hold that value, which isn't what you would want here.

Comment: The patient is one of the three types at a given moment. For example the patient can change when going from emergency (room) to inpatient (room) to outpatient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's not really how an `enum` works. You wouldn't include the `boolean` *flag*, but instead do this:

```
public enum Status {
   INPATIENT,
   OUTPATIENT,
   EMERGENCY;
}

public class Patient {
    private Status status;

    public void setStatus(final Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

public class SomeService {
     public void someMethod(final Patient patient) {
         patient.setStatus(Status.INPATIENT);
         patient.setStatus(Status.OUTPATIENT);
         patient.setStatus(Status.EMERGENCY);
    }
}
```

A variable typed as an `enum` can hold any one value of that `enum` (or `null`). If you want to change status, change which value of the enum the variable refers to. (`Enum`s are different from `class`es, since they are not instantiated with the `new` keyword, but rather just referenced directly, as in the above code.)

Comment: I get an warning on "private Status status;" for this variable isn't being used?  Shouldn't enum Status be inside of Patient class or no?

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum StatusFlag { OUTPATEINT, INPATIENT, EMERGENCY}

public class Patient {

    private StatusFlag status;

    // Here goes more code
}
```

This will ensure that it would be impossible to assign any other values to `status` field.